# Add a script as an application

Tags: software-installation

While using ubuntu some packages are available as standalone application available in .tar.gz packages. These application can be ran by executing executable file within the folder. Now I want to manage a particular file format using this application but application isn't visible in open with menu. What can I do.

Comment: Which application, and which file format? Most packages you need you should be able to install to the system using `apt-get` and packages from the repositories .

Comment: Ubuntu Apt repository didn't contain the latest version of those softwares and it is easier for me to save those application in other partition rather than utilizing my OS space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the method. I just created a document file for the application I needed with execution path given as location of script, icon, and mime type etc. Saved it as application.desktop and copied it to /usr/share/application. Now the os recognises that script as application and it is visible in application menu as well as open with menu etc.